# How to get RevisionType from RevisionEntity with Hibernate Envers?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-envers

I have simple Audited entity and Am using envers to track changes on a specif field.

I have the necessity to distinguish between an Entity + RevisionEntity's RevisionType: if it is either MOD, ADD or DEL.

How to achieve this with envers?

I know that the info is the AUD tables, but Am unable to retrieve it via regular mapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using a custom RevisionEntity + RevisionEntityListener in order to achieve this behaviour:

```
public class UsuarioRevisionListener implements RevisionListener, EntityTrackingRevisionListener {

    @Override
    public void newRevision(Object revisionEntity) {
    }

    @Override
    public void entityChanged(Class entityClass, String entityName, Serializable entityId, RevisionType revisionType, Object revisionEntity) {
        UsuarioRevisionEntity revision = (UsuarioRevisionEntity) revisionEntity;
        revision.getEntityRevType().put(UsuarioRevisionEntity.chave(entityClass,entityId), revisionType);
    }
}
```

And my revision entity:

```
@Entity
@RevisionEntity(UsuarioRevisionListener.class)
public class UsuarioRevisionEntity extends DefaultTrackingModifiedEntitiesRevisionEntity {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4211821630661371266L;

    @ElementCollection(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name="REVTYPE")
    @MapKeyColumn(name="NAMEID")
    @CollectionTable(name="ENT_REVTYPE", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="REV"))
    @Getter @Setter
    private Map<String,RevisionType> entityRevType = new HashMap<>();

    public <T extends Entidade> Optional<RevisionType> getRevType(T entity) {
        return Optional.fromNullable(entityRevType.get(chave(entity.getClass(),entity.getId())));
    }

    public static String chave(Class entityClass, Serializable entityId) {
        return String.format("%s-%s",entityClass.getSimpleName(),entityId.toString());
    }
}
```

This solution basically keeps track of each entity class+id that was changed/added/deleted at that Revision and queries it to know which RevisionType marks that Revision for a given Entity.

Comment: you don't need to implement both RevisionListener and EntityTrackingRevisionListener.  EntityTrackingRevisionListener extends RevisionListener